# K theory as the fundamental group

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology, noncommutative-geometry

There are several ways in which one can define $K$-theory for $C^*$-algebras: for $K_0(A)$ group two aproaches: algebraic (using *idempotents*) and topological (using *projections*, i.e. self-adjoint idempotents) are equivalent. However recently I read that $K_0(A)$ may be defined as $\pi_1(GL_{\infty}(A))$ (the fundamental group of invertible matrices of arbitrary size over $A$). How to prove that fact?

Comment: Here's a sketch.  $GL_n(A)$ deformation retracts onto $U_n(A)$, so $K_1(A)$ (homotopy classes of unitaries over $A$) is isomorphic to $\pi_0(GL_\infty(A))$.  But $\pi_1(GL_\infty(A)) \cong \pi_0(\Sigma GL_\infty(A)) \cong \pi_0(GL_\infty(\Sigma A)) \cong K_1(\Sigma A)$, where $\Sigma$ means suspension.  Now apply Bott periodicity.  (I'm being fast and loose with basepoints / unitalizations here, but that's the general idea.)

Comment: Come to think of it, I find it a bit strange to think of this as a "definition" of $K_0(A)$ - Bott probably would have called this an example of "that old French trick of turning a theorem into a definition".  Funny that somebody did it to Bott's own theorem.

Comment: You can also recover the natural pre-ordering on K${}_0$ by looking at the set images of loops of the form $\exp 2\pi  i t p$ where $p$ is a projection (in some matrix algebra over the C*-algebra).

Comment: @Paul Siegel thank you for your comment. Looks very reasonable however let me ask: is this first isomorphism obvious? Namely suspension is defined as $\Sigma A=C_0(\mathbb{R}) \otimes A \cong C_0(\mathbb{R} \to A)$ and the fundamental group is defined in terms of _loops_ so does these two object coincide?

Comment: @truebaran In the first isomorphism we suspend $GL_\infty(A)$ as a topological space, not a C*-algebra (I don't see any natural C*-algebra structure on it).  In the second step we pass to the C*-algebra suspension of $A$, but it is here where we should be careful about basepoints and such: I think the right thing to do is use the unitalization of $\Sigma A$ instead of $\Sigma A$, so that we get $C(S^1) \otimes A$ in the case where $A$ is unital.  If $A$ is non-unital then you have to be more careful, but the definition of $K_1$ is rigged to make everything work out.

Comment: Thank you, if you rewrite it as an answer (providing some more details or not) I will accept it.